# JSON to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to use JSON, I'm getting the information from the server so I've written this PHP file:

```
     include("db_connect.php");

      mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
      @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

      $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
      $query = "SELECT * FROM models WHERE models.product_id='".$product_selected."'";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $json_object =  "{ \"model\": [";

       while($result_row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
         $json_object .= " {\"model_name\" : \"".$result_row[1]."(".$result_row[2].")";
         $json_object .= "\"},";

        }
           $json_object = substr($json_object,0,strlen($json_object)-1);
           $json_object .= " ]};";

           echo  json_encode($json_object);
```

?>

The output of the PHP file is in JSON format like this:

```
{ "model":
           [
              {"model_name" : "xxxxx "},
              {"model_name" : "xxxxx "},
              {"model_name" : "link2(U)"},
              {"model_name" : "xxxxx)"}
           ]
  };
```

But i'm getting this response in Ajax like:

```
var my_JSON_object = {};
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
  try {
         xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajaxproduct_new.php?product_id=" product_id,true);
         xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
              my_JSON_object = JSON.parse( xmlHttp.responseText );

             alert(my_JSON_object.model[0].model_name);
              }
  }
             xmlHttp.send(null);

   } catch (e){
           alert("Can't connect to server:\" e.toString());
}
```

But when I'm doing alert of `my_JSON_object.model[0].model_name` it showing the error as
`my_JSON_object.model` is undefined.

Why is it coming like this? I have tried all the stuffs. Can any one please tell me?

Comment: How are you constructing the JSON

Comment: Can you edit and add the responseText to your question. Maybe it's malformed.

Comment: That’s not JSON. The `;` is illegal in JSON.

Comment: at very first, the browser displays all the product name, then when user clicks on the particular product, all the models related to that product will gets displayed, i'm using ajax call to get the corresponding models as u see the above php file for getting the models from mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to do anything with `data.model[0].model_name` before you know what `data` is sounds bad to me. And even if it just for testing something, `eval` won't really help you.

So, the first step in debugging this would be to alert the `xmlHttp.responseText` variable!

- If it doesn't look like you expect it to do, then the server is the issue.
- If it does look like you expect it to do, then you have some problem client side (or you've missed something about what's valid in json).

That being said, Felix's answer is probably the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a string that looks like JSON and pass this to `json_encode`, which is wrong. `json_encode` accepts an object or an array. So, create an array instead of a string:

```
$data = array();

while(($result_row = mysql_fetch_row($result))) {
    $data = array('model_name' => $result_row[1] . '(' . $result_row[2] .')');
}

echo json_encode(array('model' => $data));
```

Your JavaScript code looks ok.

Comment: thankz a lot!!! now it working , but in this line of code there is some error , so the correct code should be like this $data[] = array('model_name' => $result_row[1] . '(' . $result_row[2] .')');
once again thankzzzzzzz

Comment: @SivaRamakrishnan: Oh yes, I missed the closing parenthesis :) Fixed. Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking on the tick outline next to it ;)

Comment: how to find out the length of the particular json array when i'm doing alert(my_JSON_object.length) it showing me undefined

Comment: @SivaRamakrishnan: Because `my_JSON_object` is an object and not an array. It has no property length. `my_JSON_object.model` contains the array, so you have to do `my_JSON_object.model.length`.

Comment: @SivaRamakrishnan: :D Just keep on practicing and reading :) Happy coding!

Comment: @SivaRamakrishnan: Well, there are probably a lot. I suggest you search here on Stackoverflow for common problems you have and have a look how other people solve it.

Answer (score 0):

try the following lines of codes
 var data = eval("(" + xmlHttp.responseText + ")");
 alert(data.model[0].model_name)

Comment: eval is not recommended but for now to get quick result use eval, if the problem is still exist then try to explore your server side code

Comment: No i had tried  the same error is coming data.model is undefined

Comment: If this does not work: `eval("var data ="+xmlHttp.responseText); alert(data.model[0].model_name);` then there is a data issue

Comment: And what useful thing could the `eval` tell us that a simple `alert` could not?

Comment: Assuming the data looked correct, and we all assumed it did until we learned otherwise, the eval would give errors if the json was malformed as it turned out to be.

Comment: xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajaxproduct_new.php?product_id=" product_id,true);  put + sign before product_id